# Get Current Running Process in Android

Tags: android

It's about Currently Running Process Info.

I would like to capture the vivid name or the same name which appeared under icon of the current running process.

While using  [RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html) or [RunningProcessInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html) , I can only get the complex information like com.android.browser.

Actually, I want to get the names like Brower, Clock, Contact etc.

How can I achieve this? Please direct to the full tutorial link or with fully explanation codes.

PS: I am just a beginner and I am sure that I've already explored the Android Developer site.

Comment: There's example code for a simple home screen somewhere you can easily find (forget if its actually in the sdk samples or not), which should show you how to get the labels and even icons.

Answer (score 2):

Get the current RunningAppProcessInfo from pid

```
public static String getCurrentProcessName(Context context) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentProcessName");
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses())
    {
        // Log.d(TAG, processInfo.processName);
        if (processInfo.pid == pid)
            return processInfo.processName;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the package name (such as com.android.browser), simply use that name with PackageManager:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(name, 0);
CharSequence name = pm.getApplicationLabel(ai);
```

You'll need to handle some exceptions, but you will get the real app names from this.

Comment: It will not work if application has different name label ad process name

Comment: If one have the package name (as found in RunningProcessInfo.BaseActivity), this will definitely return the app name from it. Sure enough the label will differ from the process name, but that's the point of it.